# Android: FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS is not providing correct screen height

Tags: android

In my application, I am displaying list of cards. If first card is visible then status bar translucent and non-translucent for other list items. To achieve this I have used

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
```

It is shifting screen and I am not getting correct screen height. I have set list item height as match parent but getHeight is returning height value as screen height - status bar height.

Comment: After adding FLAOG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, I need some callback once screen size has changed to full screen, so that I can modify the view padding. My issue is, after adding window flag, I am changing view padding which call onLayout method. Here I don't get correct screen height (It always return screen height - status bar height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting TreeObserver on Window view has worked for me. After adding FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, added tree observer and inside it I set the parent view padding which had invoked onLayout method of the parent view and painted layout properly

```
getWindow().getDecorView().getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

            }
});
```